# How to find an integrating factor?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand the integrating factor technique starting with a simple case to see how it develops into more complicated structures.

Suppose I have a differential equation I want to solve of the for $y'(x) = g(x)y(x)$ where $g(x)$ is known and $y(x)$ is not.

Now although the general solution to this is already known, suppose I'm just starting out and I make a guess of the form $Ce^{f(x)}$ where $f(x)$ is known and this guess gives me $Cf'(x)e^{f(x)}$ but it doesn't give me exactly the right solution though it does appear related, that it instead it gives me something like $C\frac{d}{dx}e^{f(x)} = Ch(x)g(x)e^{f(x)}.$

How can I derive an integrating factor $I(x)$ that fixes this guess and leads to the solution $f(x) = \int_{1}^{x}g(t)dt$?

Comment: your differential equation is separable...

Comment: That is much too little information to be helpful. How does this relate to the more general notion of integrating factors? Keep in mind I explicitly stated " although the general solution to this is already known", I'm already aware of the general solution so I'm not looking for alternative methods, I'm asking specifically how *integrating factors* can be used to derive it.

Comment: What is $h(x)$? What part of the equation do you try to address with $Ce^{f(x)}$? If you do everything a little more carefully, you should automatically get to your claim $f'(x)=g(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem with the separable differential equation:
$$y'(x)=g(x)y(x)$$
If you try to solve it with integrating factor method then you have:
$$y'(x)\mu-\mu g(x)y(x)=0$$
$$\implies -\mu g(x) = \mu '$$
So that you have:
$$y'(x) \mu(x)+y(x) \mu'(x)=0$$
$$(y(x) \mu(x))'=0$$
So in order to solve an original separable differential equation with the integrating factor method, you have to solve another seprable DE to find the integrating factor $\mu $. This is where the problem is.

---

Starting from the DE:
$$-\mu g(x) = \mu '$$
$$\dfrac {\mu '}{\mu}=-g(x)$$
$$(\ln \mu)'=-g(x)$$
Integrate
$$\ln \mu (x)=-\int g(x)dx+c$$
$$\implies \mu(x)=Ce^{-\int g(x)dx}$$
Then you have that :
$$y(x)=\dfrac {c}{\mu(x)}$$
$$y(x)=ke^{\int g(x)dx}$$

Comment: Please try to use the variables I used in the original post, I am not entirely sure what you're posting because you renamed everything and didn't specify which are constants and functions. 

Can you also be more concise in what you're saying? Are you trying to suggest that you can derive the integrating factor by solving another type of separable differential equation? Or are you saying that no integrating factor exists because the problem degenerates to a separable differential equation? It isn't clear to me when you are not explicit in your steps.

Comment: Yes you need to solve another separable de in order to find the integrating factor Thats exactly that. @CheeseMongoose. i changed the notation I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Alright thank you, I will try to go through the steps.

Comment: You're welcome. @CheeseMongoose

Comment: For the third equation, how did you calculate the derivative of the integrating factor? If you differentiated the preceding line then shouldn't the equation now be second order?

Comment: Remember the rule of the derivative of a product of two functions ? $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ so  thats the property I used. @CheeseMongoose

Comment: For the integrating factor you can find it by solving the separable DE with $\mu(s)$

Comment: Alright thanks. So if I were to solve $(y(x)\mu(x))' = 0,$ I would get $y(x)\mu(x)  = c$ for some constant $c \in \mathbb{R}.$  But then doesn't this imply $y(x) = \frac{c}{\mu(x)} $? But the solution s supposed to be something like $c \cdot e^{\int_{1}^{t} g(s)ds}$ so what went wrong?

Comment: You get $y(x)\mu(x)=c$ because the derivative of a  consarnt is zero where the derivative of x is $1$ @CheeseMongoose

Comment: Right I'm not disputing that, I just mean I thought the integrating factor was supposed to lead to the correct solution, but somehow it didn't which is weird. How does one obtain $\int_{1}^{t}g(s)ds$ from this? I'm not even sure if you're saying there was a mistake because it's just too vague for me to discern. We don't know what $y(x)$ is, we only know $g(x).$

Comment: I added some lines in my answer I hope it"s more clear. @CheeseMongoose

Comment: Thank you, I think where I went wrong is assuming I had an $ u' v + v' u $ but that $\mu(x)g(x) = v'$, but all you did was multiply both sides by $\mu,$ then assumed the right-hand factor was a derivative of the left-hand factor $\mu.$

Comment: You got it it's exactly that. And thats what it's meant by an integrating factor @CheeseMongoose

Comment: I posted another question asking about a problem I don't know how to resolve  related to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3737152/how-to-clear-up-this-ambiguity-in-integrating-factor