# How to clear up this ambiguity in integrating factor?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[How to find an integrating factor?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736672/how-to-find-an-integrating-factor/3736777?noredirect=1#comment7683346_3736777)

Suppose I have a differential equation I want to solve of the for $y'(x) = g(x)y(x)$ where $g(x)$ is known and $y(x)$ is not.

In the above link's answer, I'm noticing more rigorously that there is this sort of circular logic. So the product rule says $\frac{d}{dt}[a(t)b(t)] = a' b + b' a$ and we're trying to find something that reverse-engineers that process.

Suppose in that second equation in the answer that we label $y(x)$ as $a$ and $b'$ as $\mu(x) g(x).$ Well, this is ambiguous because then I'm saying $a = y \implies a' = y',$ but this cannot be true, $a'$ should actually be $y(x)g(x)$ because we said $y = a$ and the construction of the problem assumes $y' =  g(x)y(x),$ yet somehow it magically all works out.  How is this resolved?

Comment: Its both true that $a'=gy$ and that $a'=y'$, why is this a problem?

Comment: Furthermore what is wrong with $$y' - gy = 0 \iff e^{\int_1^x g} g' - ge^{\int_1^x g}y = 0 \iff (e^{\int_1^x g} y)' = 0 \iff y = Ce^{-\int_1^x g}$$?

Comment: You have a sign mistaje @CalvinKhor for the integrating factor it should be $-g$ in the intragrand

Comment: haha I did ask what was wrong. Can't edit the comment anymore, thanks for pointing it out @Aryadeva. Hopefully OP understands my point

Comment: Yes Op will understand your good point. @CalvinKhor

Answer (score 1):

Integrating factor is **not** needed for solving $y' = g(x)y$. Symbolically,
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = g(x)y\tag{-1}
$$
can be solved by
$$
\int\frac{dy}{y}=\int g(x)dx\;.\tag{0}
$$

In general, if you want to find an integral factor, you should write the equation into the "canonical" form
$$
y'+p(x)y=q(x)\tag{1}
$$
and follow the standard procedures to find an integrating factor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#Solving_first_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations

---

OK. Let me say a bit more.

Your goal of solving (1) is to find **one* integrating factor $m(x)$ so that
$$
my'+mpy=N'(x)
$$
for some function $N(x)$. Observe by the chain rule that
$$
(my)'=my'+m'y\;.
$$
So **IF** $m'y=mpy$, then you can set $N(x)=m(x)y(x)$. Note my words: I do not say it **must** be that $m'y=mpy$. All you need is **one** way to find such a factor. So all you need is a function $m$ with
$$
m'(x)=m(x)p(x)\;.
$$

Now you are essentially in the situation of equation (-1).

Comment: Okay, but I'm still interested in understanding from the ground up in the case $q(x) = 0.$

Comment: @CheeseMongoose: you simply take $q=0$ in the standard procedures. Actually the integrating factor you get only depends on $p$.

Comment: Yeah I read that wiki article multiple times before coming here and it didn't answer everything, hence why I came here.

Comment: @CheeseMongoose: that article give you **one** integrating factor. It is not necessarily *unique*.

Comment: @CheeseMongoose: check my updates.

Answer (score 0):

For the following DE:
$$y'(x)=g(x)y(x)$$
$$\mu(x)y'(x)-\mu(x)g(x)y(x)=0$$
Is of the form:
$$a'b+b'a=0 \implies (ab)'=0$$
If you consider $a=y;a'=y'$ and $b=\mu(x),b'=-\mu(x)g(x)$.

This implies that:
$$\mu'(x)=-\mu(x) g(x)$$

Comment: But this relabeling leads to the same problem I mentioned in the post. By construction we have that $y' = g(x)y(x),$ so if $a = y,$ then $a'$ must be $g(x)y(x).$

Comment: Yes but then you can do nothing. Because you have two unknown y and a @CheeseMongoose

Comment: But saying "it works because otherwise it doesn't work" isn't a logically consistent argument. What is the reason why it works when you've already used up $g(x)$ for a different renaming?

Comment: I am not sure to get your point. We solve the DE to find the integrating factor then we can solve the orifinal DE. @CheeseMongoose

Comment: I didnt change the meaning of $g(s)$ Take a concrete example.